# Regarding crawler politeness and to cross verify whether am doing it right?

Tags: java, web-crawler

I am trying to build a crawler for my project and just came across the politeness issue [And I have understood the need of it]. I have started with the following code in java:

```
try{
  URL seedPage = new URL("SeedPage to fetch");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(seedPage.openStream()));
  String line="";
  while(null != (line = br.readLine()){
     TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2) //2 seconds of delay here and the question lies here.
     //do Something
  }
} catch (Exception ex){
}
```

Am doing this [politeness] right way? I hope I am not putting any burden on the server which processes my request.

Answer (score 1):

It's OK to receive the page as fast as the server sends it. After all, people use web browsers such as Firefox and those receive each page as fast as they can.

The politeness issue occurs when you want to read more than one page, usually by following the links in each page. Then the most appropriate behavior is for you, the human being to read the terms of use on each site and see what they say you're allowed to do. The next alternative behavior is to put a delay between reading one page and reading the next page on the same site. After all, people don't move from page to page instantly.

You should be aware that if some site judges that your crawler is abusive, that site may refuse to respond to any more requests from your internet address for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Delaying reading of a single element actually blocks one server slot longer than necessary, so it it rather impolite behaviour (although meaning to be polite). As minopret has pointed out, pausing after a single request **and releasing** the connection in the meantime may be a way to be more friendly to the server. If you perform only one request at a time, even with no delays this should not be a problem for any server, but the sites policy may say somthing else.

But an even more important point is that you should honor `robots.txt` file and avoid crawling elements that are excluded in there.

Also you should send cookies that you have received, otherwise some sites will open new sessions for every request that you make. This may unnecessarily eat up resources until the sessions time out.